# How to set priority on s3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to upload multiple files in a s3 bucket. Suppose I have a file of bigger size whose upload is in progress. Now I get a file for smaller size which I want to upload first in the same bucket. Could we set some priority or scheduling mechanism at file level while uploading?

Comment: Set it where? "In S3?"  S3 doesn't really know you're doing these parallel uploads, because each incoming request is handled independently on that end.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload multiple files to Amazon S3, which is highly scalable and has significant bandwidth.

The limitation would most probably be your own Internet bandwidth and your ability to perform multiple uploads in parallel.

If you do not wish to write your own application to upload multiple files to S3, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which includes an `aws s3 sync` command that will copy files to S3 -- whenever run, it will only copy new or changed files, thus allowing you to *synchronize* local files with S3.